# Discord.py-rewrite has_role command error (not a console error)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello Guys this is my code of discord.py

```
@commands.command()
    async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        if commands.has_role('Server Manager'):
            await member.kick(reason=reason)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Sorry! You don't have the permission for that")
```

If i have the `Server Manager` role i can kick members normaly but my friend doesn't yet he can also kick with the command i don't want that to happen so please help :(.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is not quite clear to me what you mean by 'my friend doesn't yet he can also kick with the command'. Can you further clarify the exact problem?

Comment: I mean he doesn't have the role 'Server Manager' yet he's able to kick members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a check, so you would use it as you do all of the other [checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks). Here is an example:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_role("Server Manager")
async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

This will then either let the user kick the member, or raise an error as stated in [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.ext.commands.has_role). You would want to check for [commands.MissingRole](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.ext.commands.MissingRole) in your error handler.